# Why is absolute pitch so fetished/sought after in the Western music world?

Tags: absolute-pitch, relative-pitch

I often come across accomplished musicians with good relative pitch (can figure out melodies, chord progressions) beating themselves up for not having absolute pitch. In general, reading people's writings on Western music leave me with the impression that absolute pitch is the Holy Grail of aural skills.

Why is this? Unless you want to play atonal music by ear, isn't relative pitch good for everything else?

(Here, I am referring to the ability to give a note name to a frequency. There are other skills like pitch resolution - i.e. figuring out the names to many notes played simultaneously, and aural memory - i.e. being able to reproduce music of varying complexity after hearing it a certain number of times, but those seem like skills that someone with relative pitch can also possess.)

Comment: Not even sure it is. More like a *bete noir* to a lot of folk who have it, it seems.

Comment: For one reason only: you never need a tuning device ;-)

Comment: I’ll say this: those I’ve met with perfect pitch who are also musicians are very, very capable in music.

Comment: You should be able to recognize pitches, chords and scales when done with any sort of conserve training. Scales, chords, intervals and pitches all have unique sounds, it is not that hard to learn to recognize them

Comment: @NeilMeyer - what *kind* of chords, what *sort* of scales, absolutely. But pitches? Relative, yes, but even having training doesn't endow one with absolute pitch. Seems it's something on either has or has not. Are you saying that we ought to be able to tell an E from an F note if we went to a Conservatoire? I disagree!

Comment: In my experience, good musicians with well trained RP are not annoyed by the fact that they don't have AP; yes, sometimes it *is* useful and in those moments we (me being one of them) could momentarily think "oh, if I had...". But, actually, there are often more benefits from RP than downsides. On the contrary, some AP people I met are actually annoyed by it, as it can become a *huge* limitation if not properly trained (esp. for transposition or using different tunings). And, well, I also met some that, *because* of their view on how "wonderful" AP is, are *actually* annoying people  ;-)

Comment: I suspect confirmation bias may well play into this perception if it exists. Also, I once read a web article claiming Michael Jackson had perfect pitch. Their highly-suspect justification was that he spent a long time warming up... People in the West (nonmusicians, particularly) do tend to misunderstand what perfect pitch is, and that likely has some effect on any special esteem of the condition.

Comment: @Creynders - this could be awkward - depending which part of the world one is in, and what pitch (Hz) A equals!

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard any "accomplished musicians with good relative pitch beating themselves up for not having absolute pitch", but I have heard many many beginners wishing they had it because it seems to them like a superpower that allows them to play anything just by hearing...

Comment: IMO, it does indeed seem to be a fetish, but for those who aren't accomplished i.e. who haven't spent enough hours practicing. Just like "how many languages do you speak" is a bit of a fetish and a status symbol in cultures where people generally only speak one language, because they never had to learn anything else. You can add "absolute-pitch" on your list of ignored tags to make this fetish disappear from your view. If you bump into the fetish stuff accidentally, tag it with absolute-pitch to make it go away.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're attacking a straw man here.  Yes, good aural skills are very important to a musician.  But in 65-odd years of dealing with musicians - and striving towards becoming one - I've never experienced such a yearning expressed by myself or others.

Of course, good 'relative pitch' DOES enable atonal sight-singing.  Once a reference pitch is established, I (like any trained musician) can sing any interval, not just the 'easy' ones.

And some degree of perfect pitch does develop in many musicians.  I personally find it very hard to play a keyboard with a transposition function switched in.  Which is a nuisance, as this ought to be a boon to an accompanist!  When I play and the 'wrong' pitches come out, it can quite throw me.  (Hey! Perhaps I DO have perfect pitch!)

When I was at college, we were required to transcribe a passage of 'atonal' 4-part harmony.    Those of us with some jazz experience  often found ourselves recognising patterns that the pure classicists heard as random dissonance.    That's the trouble with atonal music - tonal keeps catching up with it!

Comment: Anyone care to justify the dv?

Comment: @Tim Instead of providing an answer to this interesting question, it's frame-challenge that uses one anecdotal piece of evidence to try to disprove the entire premise of a question. Don't ask me, because I'm **not** the person who downvoted it, but if I *had*, that would have been my explanation.

Comment: @user45266 - thanks for your input. I did consider that the question was asked under false premises. I don't believe that AP is 'sought after'. So why is the question deemed valid?

Comment: @Tim Apparently downvoter strongly agrees with OP, thinking that absolute pitch is revered and thus disapproves of this deflection away from the question? That's my guess. Or just random - that does happen.

Comment: @user45266 - sheer supposition, which is all any of us could provide. Pity though, as with a posted reason, we could all attempt to understand. My perennial moan...

Comment: A question based on an incorrect premise is valid.  But it must be accepted that refuting  the premise is a full and sufficient answer!  The only 'answer' to 'Why is the sky green?' is 'It isn't!'

Comment: I think it is indeed somewhat of a fetish, but only for those who haven't practiced enough and so don't have the skills to operate in music fluently. For those, this seemingly magical gift seems so fascinating - an instant way to another level of consciousness. Like improvisation and playing by ear - for those who haven't spent the hours to learn it, it seems so magical and desireable, like "oh I wish I had this special supernatural ability." But there's no trick, no product to buy, no gene to be born with, there's just lots of hard work and training.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - so you believe that AP can be learned - by anyone - with enough practice? I don't.

Comment: Confusion between absolute pitch and relative pitch I think.   The latter is completely trainable.

Comment: @Tim No. I was trying to say that those who have this fetish haven't practiced enough to get the skills to operate, and they see absolute pitch as some kind of magical thing. Those who have learned the skills to handle music see absolute pitch as a nice extra gimmick, if that, not a requirement. If you have it, can be nice, maybe, but does it make your music better? Who cares about your having perfect pitch or not, and what do they do with that information? What is the utility and purpose of talking about perfect pitch. Attribution of mystical qualities to this thing = fetish.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.  Someone with a 'good ear' can certainly achieve great abilities with practise and experience.  There is a downside to having perfect pitch for sure.  When playing (or listening to) say Baroque music, especially in period performance groups, the pitch can be quite a lot lower than the usual A 440.  This can be excruciating for someone with perfect pitch.